# Ajax error in draggableviews

Tags: drupal, view, draggable

We're trying to sort a view with draggableviews 7.x - 2.0 but when attempting to save the we get the following error:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred. 
HTTP Result Code: 500 
Debugging information follows. 
Path: /admin/structure/views/ajax/preview/jnytt_modul_nyhetsslider/panel_pane_2/387 
StatusText: error 
ResponseText: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field &#039;nid&#039;     
doesn&#039;t have a default value: INSERT INTO {draggableviews_structure} (view_name,   
view_display, args, entity_id, weight) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,   
:db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, 
:db_insert_placeholder_4); Array 
( 
[:db_insert_placeholder_0] =&gt; jnytt_modul_nyhetsslider 
[:db_insert_placeholder_1] =&gt; panel_pane_2 
[:db_insert_placeholder_2] =&gt; [&quot;387&quot;] 
[:db_insert_placeholder_3] =&gt; 9988 
[:db_insert_placeholder_4] =&gt; 0 
)
```

Anyone else who have had this problem and found a solution because I sure as h*** can't find one :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your db table draggableviews_structure has a field **nid** that needs a default value. This is outdated because the version 2.x of  draggableviews uses **entity_id** instead. Maybe you upgraded from 1.x to 2.x which is not possible.

> There is no upgrade path from 7.x-1.x to 7.x-2.x branch
>   http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews

So either reinstall to module or edit the database table manually. I would suggest reinstalling via [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel)

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer Steff. Will try it out on wednesday :)